# PoseNet experimentation

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I want to reproduce the results of this paper **PoseNet: A Convolutional Network for Real-Time 6-DOF Camera Relocalization** Alex Kendall, Matthew Grimes and Roberto Cipolla.

I have a dumb question regarding the required version of Caffe . Can I experiment with the standard version of Caffe provided on BVLC repository or I should do my experiments with their modified version of Caffe [caffe PoseNet](https://github.com/alexgkendall/caffe-posenet)

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you try it with BVLC or another third-party Caffe?  Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the results of the paper above with a BVLC version of Caffe because there is difference specially in data layer [link](https://github.com/alexgkendall/caffe-posenet/compare/cff6f3d...62aafbd#diff-54b85267f183e064db0be7b057b0577fR45).
I succeed to reproduce the results of the paper with the modified version of Caffe . For the installation , I followed this [documentation](https://github.com/alexgkendall/caffe-posenet/blob/master/docs/installation.md)